# How to replace one string with another in whole application in android?

Tags: android

I have to change one text with another when user select option from settings,For example
I have to change Kilometers in to miles when user select it from option. And When i select it
i have to change kilometer into Miles thought the application , Please help me if anyone knows 
how to do it?

Comment: use sharedpreferences

Comment: explain more, is it a list ? a text view or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare these globally for convenience:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
Editor editor;
private static final String PRIVATE_PREF = "current_selection";
```

And then in the `onCreate()` or it's equivalent:

```
sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// SET THE DEFAULT VALUE
editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("value", "kilometers");

// DONT SKIP THIS STEP
editor.commit();
```

Finally, wherever you need to check which of the two is the current selected value (*Kilometers / Miles*):

```
String strSetting = sharedPrefs.getString("value", null);
```

Now, you can use the `String strSetting` to check the value of the setting, and run the appropriate code. I am assuming it has something to do with conversion perhaps.

NOTE: If you are using the above (retrieving) in another `Activity`, you will need to instantiate this again:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String strSetting = sharedPrefs.getString("value", null);
```

Anytime you want to change the setting, just use the first piece of code. For example, if you change from Kilometers to Miles:

```
// SET THE A NEW VALUE
editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("value", "miles");

// DONT SKIP THIS STEP
editor.commit();
```

You can read more about [SharedPreferences here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static String in your MainActivity (or elsewhere).

```
class MainActivity {
   public static String distance = "kilometer";
}
```

You can change the String from anywhere with

```
MainActivity.distance = "miles";
```

Then you can use the distance String allover your app.

Comment: good.. but its work for one time.. when i start app again then its give me "kilometer";

Comment: Then search for SharedPreferences, you'll find a lot of info on how to use them. Write a boolean or a String or whatever to the SHaredPrefs, containing the users selection. When your app loads, you load the SharedPref and set you global static "distance" accordingly.